# how to dismiss dialog in handler

Tags: android

I have problem. I have a progressbar and I show it when run a thread. When I completed handle on thread I update UI with a handler but in handler when I cancel progressbar and when I show a other dialog the progressbar still display.

Can anybody please tell me how can I use the Handler to dismiss the Progress Dialog?

Thanks,

Comment: please share you code.

Comment: Please elaborate more or share code

Comment: you can cancel or dismiss the progressbar with the same thread which launched it.

Answer (score 1):

use it in oncreate methed

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Logo_Activity.this);
    dialog.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: why you used 5000 here ?

Comment: after 5 secand dialog will dismiss

Comment: why can not 500 here ?

Comment: Because `1000 = 1 sec` so `5000 = 5sec`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    final Handler handler=new Handler();
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do somthing
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();// or dialog.cancel()

                }
            });             
        }
    });
    t.start();
```